# How to enabling JavaScript button click function to work after a time limit?

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I wish to allow this JavaScript Button to show other page (active) only when it was continuously clicked for 10 second. Any help would be highly appreciated. e.g. if it was clicked for less than 10 second, it shouldn't call the function and nothing happens.

```js
             

             function callAnothePage()
             {
                window.location = "https://www.bbc.com/";
             }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!doctype html>
<html class="no-js" lang="">
 
    <body>
        

       <button name="buttonClick" class="button" onclick="callAnothePage()"
       id="btnMakeCall" >how</button>
    
 

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand, do you mean you want the button to show the page after being clicked and 10 seconds has passed or?

Comment: i want button to show other page , only if it was continuously pressed for 10 second. if some one press less than 10 second , that button shouldnt call next page

Comment: try to use onmousedown() with onmouseup(), this way you can detect when the mouse was clicked (onmousedown) and after how much time the user let go of it (onmouseup)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The clue is to use `onmouseup` and `onmousedown` instead of `onclick`. That way you can start a timeout when the user clicks and remove it again when they stop clicking.

```js
const button = document.querySelector( 'button' );
let timeout = null;
button.addEventListener( 'mousedown', event => {
  timeout = setTimeout(() => {
    console.log( '2 sec passed' );
  }, 2000 );
});
button.addEventListener( 'mouseup', event => {
  if ( timeout ) clearTimeout( timeout );
});
```

```html
<button>2 sec</button>
```

Comment: thank you thats what i am looking for . but when i tried on my browser i am getting this error:Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null

Comment: You have to select the correct button to bind the event to, so for your code that would be something like: `document.querySelector( '#btnMakeCall' );` Depending on how many different buttons you have, you might want to use seperate timers as well.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the user to click and hold the button for some time the answer of Shilly is a good solution.

But if you want the user to press the button again and again until the time end, maybe you should use a hit ratio instead.

With hit ratio you could define a good ratio to redirect the user and challenge the user to go over the ratio.

That way the user will click repeatedly in the button over a period of time (10 seconds) and you compare the user hit ratio (times clicked / time) with your defined ratio.

The code is something like the snippet below:

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
    var button = document.querySelector("button#clickMe");

    var clicks = 0;
    var hitRateNeeded = 3.2;
    var timeInSeconds = 10;
    var started = false;
    var timeout = null;

    button.addEventListener('click', function() {
        if (!started) {
            started = true;
            timeout = setTimeout(function() {
                freeze();
                clearAttempt();

                // do something ...
            }, timeInSeconds * 1000);            
        }

        clicks++;
    });

    function freeze() {
        var currentHitRate = clicks / timeInSeconds;
        console.log("Current Hit Rate", currentHitRate);
        console.log("Passed?", currentHitRate > hitRateNeeded)
    }

    function clearAttempt() {
        clicks = 0;
        started = false;
        clearTimeout(timeout);
    }
});
```

```html
<button id="clickMe">Click for 10 seconds</button>
```